# Common R2RML mapping file for all the tables

Tags: rdf, linked-data, r2rml, rml-rdf

I am working on a project to help the user manually import their data sources in the format of CSV or JSON, then the data will be imported into the data warehouse, after that these data sources will be automate generate to RDF Data cubes with R2RML for analytic purposes.

The problem is, I couldn't find a way to write a common R2RML structure for all the the table without declaring the exact names of existed tables and columns.

I very appreciate if someone could help me about that.

Comment: not sure if I understand, but R2RML is for relational databases. For CSV or JSON you have to go with the extension RML. But, even then, you have to define the file path as well as the columns (CSV) or the JSONPath(JSON) to map from the data source to RDF.

Comment: Yep R2RMl is for relational databases, in my case is the Data Warehouse that stores all the processed CSV and JSON files

Comment: I see. So, where is exactly are you stuck now? I mean, R2RML has the concept of "parent mappings" that can be reused, but indeed, for different column names as well as the table names, that has to be provided explicitly.